# How to redirect http to https in codeigniter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect, mod-rewrite

**Point #1**
If I type:

```
www.myurl.com/somepage
http://www.myurl.com/somepage
http://myurl.com/somepage
https://myurl.com/somepage
```

have it redirect to

```
https://www.myurl.com/somepage
```

**Point #2**

```
When I type in something like www.myurl.com it is redirecting to https://www.myurl.com/index.php.
Make it so the index.php is not displaying. It should just display https://www.myurl.com
```

From Comment htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myhost.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php(/[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*))?$ myhost.com/$2 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: set this `$route['404_override'] = '';`

Comment: already set.but same issue occure

Comment: and set your htaccess  too

Comment: how to set in htaccess?

Comment: I already set in htaccess
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.myhost.com/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php(/[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*))?$ http://www.myhost.com/$2 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
But the problem is..if i am type www.myhost.com then it redirect to www.myhost.com.
i want to redirect https://www.myhost.com.

Comment: When you need to add code you can re edit your question by clicking on the edit button below tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Now I got a solution,
I updated my htaccess file.--

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.myhost.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php(/[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*))?$ myhost.com/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Now, It worked for me smoothly.. :)

Comment: firt time if i access link with http so does not work when i refresh page then it,s convert to https why in first access it,s not convert to https directly

Answer (score 27):

I tried above all ones but they did not work properly in my case. I found below solution, it works in my case. I hope it will be helpful for you as well.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|public)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 25):

Please Check this may help

Config changes :- Go to “application/config/config.php” and enable or set hooks to true.

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

create a new file named hooks.php in “application/config/hooks.php” and add below code in hooks.php:-

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
                                'function' => 'redirect_ssl',
                                'filename' => 'ssl.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks'
                                );
```

Now create a new directory with named “hooks” under application directory and then create new file named “ssl.php” in “application/hooks/ssl.php”
and add below code to “ssl.php” :-

```
function redirect_ssl() {
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
    $exclude =  array('client');  // add more controller name to exclude ssl.
    if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {
      // redirecting to ssl.
      $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
      if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    } 
    else {
      // redirecting with no ssl.
      $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
      if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give some arguments why using this php pratice is a better method than htaccess? They both check a certain rule every run

Comment: For me, the SSL code detection did not work. Might be because we are using CloudFlare CDNto provide the SSL.

Comment: any of htaccess rewrite code didn't work for me! Hook works

Comment: The best way is to use the htaccess approach because that is the first point of call to your server. Prevents any additional computations.
Check this URL of how it works 

https://www.danielmorell.com/images/articles/htaccess_guide/daniel_morell_htaccess_rewrite_ruleset_processing_1.0.png

Answer (score 7):

Insert this into .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 5):

For Codeigniter 4, follow the path;

> /app/config/app.php

and change this line to true.

```
public $forceGlobalSecureRequests = false;
```

it will redirect to https directly. no hook, no .htaccess.

Answer (score 4):

If you, specifically want to redirect, above answers are helpful.
But if you are doing this because base is "HTTP", then,
redirecting is not correct method (as it asks for resources).
Instead, open "application/config/config.php" in your project and change the value of

```
$config['base_url']
```

Add "s" in the value
from

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
```

Comment: I added s in base_url but this , http://domaindotcom/ is not redirecting to https

Comment: manually delete the cached items in the "application/cache" folder

Answer (score 3):

for me none of the above answer worked as it was showing me too many redirects but this one worked like charm. Hence I thought to share if someone else get into the similar issue:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (sale|success|cancel) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(static|sale|success|cancel) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|static) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

First go to the application/config/config.php file and look for this line:

```
$config['base_url'] = "";
```

Set it to your URL with the https e.g. `https://example.com`

```
$config['base_url'] = "https://example.com";
```

Then go to your `.htaccess` file and add this line in the example given below.

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    #Options -Indexes
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    # Send request via index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
    

</IfModule>
```

Comment: Your first rewrite rule should not have the "[L]"

Comment: @Risteard It gave me a funny error and after a little read online I understood why, that is why I included it

Answer (score 1):

This work for me you can input it in your .htaccess just input at the last line

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes indeed this

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR] 
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ https://www.myhost.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php(/[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
   RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*))?$ myhost.com/$2 [R=301,L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

works but you have to make a slight edit. In the 
`codeiginiterfolder/application/config.php` file replace `http` with `https`.

Also, the base url in the above code you have to replace the `myhost` to your host name. Suppose my host name `internetseekho.com` so instead of `myhost` you do have write `internetseekho`.

Answer (score 0):

If you find the error ***"No Input file specified"*** then add "?" 
in the last line

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L]

in the answer from *@asiya khan*

Answer (score 0):

Our SSL is from the CloudFlare CDN and so the solutions above do not work.

The following SSL detection code  (in SSL.php based on @Preetham Hegde solution) works:

```
$isSecure = false;
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
    $isSecure = true;
}
elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https' || !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SSL'] == 'on') {
    $isSecure = true;
}
$REQUEST_PROTOCOL = $isSecure ? 'https' : 'http';


if ($REQUEST_PROTOCOL=="http")
{
    $redirect = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
    header('Location: ' . $redirect);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your existing rules. It may work!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```